# External HDD not recognized in windows 10, cmd or disk manager

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I purchased one external HDD from a shop, it work there in the shop. I took two of my own notebook HDD to check through a box. According to me, they "don't work" but they indeed work there, I saw it.

The computer used to test it has windows 7.

I also purchased a new box for them, that was used to test some of these HDD and connected like external ones to some pc desktop. When I got them home, even with the new box that was actually tested with one of the disks that it was capable of reading them none of my pc's recognized them at all.

They don't appear in the Disk Management nor the Device Manager (which, in fact, the last open the first and also the disk doesn't seem to be listed in device manager either).

Neither in the cmd (Diskpart & Chkdsk)

Also try running linux, (Ubuntu 14.something) and use lsusb & Gparted to check them, doesn't work either.

I searched on the internet and I don't know what else I can do, it is obvious to me than the problem is my computer with the box-externals hdd, because oddly enough, my USB memory sticks work just fine.

**About the HDD:** one of them have linux/windows in it the other (on of the olders), or is with mac or just files, but they aren't detected at all.

**About my PC's:** one notebook with windows 10, one desktop with windows 10 and one netbook with windows 7 starter.

Ask whatever you need to know and I'll add it to this question. In advance, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing the USB cable connecting the external case with your PCs, @Obsdark? I'd check if the HDD is recognized in the Windows 7 notebook, make sure you check Disk Management, Device Manager and even try DiskPart's command listdisks to absolutely sure that the drive is detected or not. Another thing you could try is plugging it internally (via SATA) to your PC. Check if that will get the drive recognized. It's possible that your Win 10 systems need some USB driver updates from the laptop/motherboard manufacturer's website. Keep me posted with the troubleshooting.

Comment: i update all of it in the question now, i'm gonna redo some experiments using the windows 7 and then, if doesn't work, i'm gonna try the cable, i can't try to test it before because i just have one usb-usb than is the one used in this, and i need to compare to other use, so i'm gonna try in that shop, i'll let you know how it goes, the one with the drivers can be a little tricky, did you know how can i update them?, also if you have any other idea, please just let me know.

Comment: You should go to the computer/laptop manufacturer's website. If it's a custom build, go straight to the motherboard manufacturer's website. Find your model and reinstall the USB hub drivers from the drive utilities there. Once you select your current OS version, you should be given a list of all the available drivers for your model running that particular OS version. Hope it helps you. Let me know how it goes! Good luck! :)